# Unable to run PySpark (Kafka to Delta) in local and getting SparkException: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'spark_catalog'

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks, delta-lake

I'm trying to write a PySpark code to read from the Kafka topic and publish to the Delta table. But it is not working.

Sample Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from delta import *

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("test") \
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0") \
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
        .getOrCreate()

kafka_df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "demo.topic") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .load() \
    .withColumn("current_timestamp", unix_timestamp()) \
    .withColumn("value_str", col("value").cast(StringType())) \
    .select("current_timestamp", "value_str")

stream = kafka_df.writeStream \
    .format("delta") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "./data/tmp/delta/events/_checkpoints/") \
    .toTable("events")

stream.awaitTermination()
```

Command:
Spark version: 3.3.1

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0 kafka_to_delta.py
```

Console:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/user/Desktop/python-module/kafka_to_delta.py", line 24, in <module>
        stream = kafka_df.writeStream \
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 1468, in toTable
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o63.toTable.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'spark_catalog': org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.catalogPluginClassNotFoundForCatalogError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1638)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.Catalogs$.load(Catalogs.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.loadV2SessionCatalog(CatalogManager.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.$anonfun$v2SessionCatalog$2(CatalogManager.scala:86)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.$anonfun$v2SessionCatalog$1(CatalogManager.scala:86)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.v2SessionCatalog(CatalogManager.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.catalog(CatalogManager.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.currentCatalog(CatalogManager.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog.currentCatalog(LookupCatalog.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog.currentCatalog$(LookupCatalog.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.currentCatalog(Analyzer.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog$CatalogAndIdentifier$.unapply(LookupCatalog.scala:111)
        at
:
:
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.Catalogs$.load(Catalogs.scala:55)
        ... 25 more
    
    23/01/29 18:00:53 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Do I need to specify catalog and schema, before running this code? And what is the best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0` to the list of packages passed via `--packages` (you also need to make sure that you use matching version of the `spark-sql-kafka`):

```bash
spark-submit --packages \
  org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.1,io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0 \
  kafka_to_delta.py
```

or remove `--packages` and specify Kafka dependency inside the script, although it's always better not to have specific versions inside the code, and instead provide all options outside of it.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. when I tried reading it, it says that _"pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: data/tmp/delta/events/_checkpoints is not a Delta table." _ . How would I know, which table to read since the code is creating it on the fly?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to read data from checkpoint. you need to try `spark.read.table("events")`