# Reading delta format parquet with Pyspark on EMR on EC2 cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, delta-lake

I've come across a case where I can run pyspark on a regular EC2 instance, manually pip installing pyspark and then calling the delta-core jar package dependency as a spark config as explained in other answers (e.g. [Unable to run PySpark (Kafka to Delta) in local and getting SparkException: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'spark_catalog'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275050/unable-to-run-pyspark-kafka-to-delta-in-local-and-getting-sparkexception-cann)), but get the `spark_catalog` error when running my  exact code on an EMR cluster. Has anyone ran into this and know a work around to be able to use Pyspark on an Amazon EMR cluster?
[image: spark-catalog-error]

## WORKING: Local pyspark on an EC2 notebook instance in SageMaker (Image:DS 3.0, Kernel: Python3)

```
# https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html
%pip install pyspark==3.2.0
```

and then instantiate the configured spark session using delta-core release 1.1.0 (and some other packages/configs for using s3)

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

pkg_list = [
    "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.1.0",
    "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0",
    "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.12.180" 
]
packages = ",".join(pkg_list)

spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName("EDA") 
    .config("spark.jars.packages", packages) 
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") 
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
.getOrCreate()
)

# This is mandatory config on spark session to use AWS S3
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain") 
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', <key>)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', <secret>)

print(f"Spark version: {spark.sparkContext.version}")
```

`Spark version: 3.2.0`

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("s3a://[my-bucket]/tmp/tmp/lake1/").filter(col('language')=='English')
df.show()
```

[image: working-delta-output]

## NOT WORKING: Pyspark on EMR cluster (using SageMaker notebook to run pyspark)

I select the emr release (6.6) that should installs Spark 3.2, and use the exact same code, but get the `spark_catalog` error that's indicative of incompatible package versions. Could it be something with AMZN's Spark installation not being compatible with delta-core? Since it's not "regular" `Spark 3.2` but instead `Spark version: 3.2.0-amzn-0`?

[image: emr-release]

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

pkg_list = [
    "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.1.0",
    "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0",
    "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.12.180" 
]
packages = ",".join(pkg_list)

spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName("EDA") 
    .config("spark.jars.packages", packages) 
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") 
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
.getOrCreate()
)

# This is mandatory config on spark session to use AWS S3
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain") 
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', <key>)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', <secret>)

print(f"Spark version: {spark.sparkContext.version}")
```

`Spark version: 3.2.0-amzn-0`

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("s3a://[my-bucket]/tmp/tmp/lake1/").filter(col('language')=='English')
df.show()
```

[image: spark-catalog-error]

Comment: Delta must be 2.0.0 https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html

Comment: Confirmed delta 1.1.0 works with pyspark 3.2.0 on local environment. And it's also represented in Delta's release table as supporting versions so that's not the issue unfortunately

Comment: "And it's also represented in Delta's release table as supporting versions" - Can you please clarify? According to the link above Spark 3.2.0 requires Delta 2.0.0.
"Confirmed delta 1.1.0 works with pyspark 3.2.0 on local environment" - still worth to try 2.0.0 on EMR, doesn't it?

Comment: According to the release table you also linked Spark 3.2.x works with Delta 1.1.x thru 2.0.x

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that setting the spark `.config()`s directly on the spark context itself in the notebook session was not actually setting anything.

I was setting each config once I grabbed the context from the EMR cluster and trying to set in the notebook session, but this threw the "Cannot find catalog plugin..." error each time.

Once I started setting these configs directly during the EMR cluster setup [according to these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html), the "spark_catalog" error went away and the spark context was successfully taking the configurations:
[image: emr configurations]

The call in the notebook then looks like this:

```
sc_master = sc.master
sc_app = sc.appName

spark = SparkSession.builder.master(sc_master).appName(sc_app).getOrCreate()

# This is mandatory config on spark session to use AWS S3
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain") 
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', <key>)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', <secret>)

print(f"Spark version: {spark.sparkContext.version}")
```